# STL minmax doesn't return pair properly

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

In the C++ documentation as far as I read `std::minmax_element` should return a `std::pair<obj, obj>` but when I try to return the result of the stl function I get an exception.

My class:

```cpp
class obj {       
  public:             
    int num;        
    std::string name;  
};
```

My function:

```cpp
std::pair<obj, obj> func (_Iter begin, _Iter end) const noexcept{
    return std::minmax_element(begin, end, [](const obj& l, const obj& r){
    return l.num < r.num;
});
}
```

Comment: Please read some [good documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element) about the functions you use. As you use it, I'm surprised you manage to build it actually. Unless you call the build errors "exceptions"?

Answer (score 1):

`std::minmax_element` returns pair of iterators.

You need:

```
std::pair<obj, obj> func (_Iter begin, _Iter end) const noexcept{
    auto [minIt, maxIt] = std::minmax_element(begin, end, [](const obj& l, const obj& r){
    return l.num < r.num;
});
    return {*minIt, *maxIt};
}
```

Ignoring empty range.